# Implementation of interface in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, partial-classes

I need little help with inheritance in C++. I have code with same structure like this:

```cpp
class IBase {
public:
    virtual long Dimensions() = 0;
};

class IShape : public IBase {
    virtual long Area() = 0;
};

class Rectangle : public IShape  {
private:
    long x;
public:
    long Dimensions() {return x};
    long Area() {return x*x};
};

class Rhombus: public IShape  {
private:
    long x;
    long fi;
public:
    long Dimensions() {return x};
    long Area() {return x*x*sin(fi)};
};
```

As you can see, implementation of Dimensions() is same for both classes. Now I wan't to do something like this:

```cpp
class BaseImplementation : public IBase {
protected:
    long x;
public:
    virtual long Dimensions() {return x};
};

class Rectangle : public IShape, public BaseImplementation {
public:
    long Area() {return x*x};
};

class Rhombus: public IShape, public BaseImplementation {
private:
    long fi;
public:
    long Area() {return x*x*sin(fi)};
};
```

Is possible to insert implementation of method Dimensions() into class Rhombus from BaseImplementation? Is this supported in some version of C++ standard?
Thx.

Comment: @CharlesB It’s not a bad idea in general to separate interface inheritance and mix-ins (default implementations). It’s a pretty common technique.

Comment: @user1173308 What do you mean exactly by "insert implementation of method into class"? Do you want to override the behaviour of `Dimensions()` for the `Rhombus` class?

Comment: @KonradRudolph: thanks, I'm not used to this. deleted comment as it was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your hierarchy is that your `Rectangle` now inherits `IBase` twice: once through `IShape`, and once through `BaseImplementation`. C++ feature called [Virtual Inheritance](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html#faq-25.9) is designed to deal with situations like that. Note that you need to make `IShape`'s inheriting `IBase` `virtual public` as well.

Answer (score 1):

If `Dimensions()` is implemented in `BaseImplementation`, and is at least `protected` in access, it should be visible to any derived object.

So `Rhombus` will be able to use the `Dimension()` function if it is derived from `BaseImplementation`.  If you want to have a specific implementation for `Dimension()` in case of a `Rhombus`, your `Dimension()` should be `virtual` and you should override it in `Rhombus`

Comment: If a try to create object Rhombus. The GCC(g++) shows this error: cannot declare variable 'xyz' to be of abstract type 'Rhombus' note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'Rhombus': virtual long int IBase::Dimensions()

Answer (score 1):

You could simply implement a layer in between that defines Dimension:

```
class IBase {
public:
    virtual long Dimensions() = 0;
};

class IShape : public IBase {
public:
    virtual long Area() = 0;
};

class IShapesDefinedDimension : public IShape
{
public:
   long Dimensions() { return x; }
protected:
    long x;
};

class Rectangle : public IShapesDefinedDimension  {
public:
    long Area() {return x*x;}
};

class Rhombus: public IShapesDefinedDimension  {
public:
    long Area() {return x*x*sin(fi); }
...
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to explicitly insert the implementation. You can already call
myRhombus->Dimension() because it is inherited.